# Failed to build atlas examples with cabal

Tags: smart-contract, atlas

I tried both in the main branch and in the atlas-0.3-update branch and get the same result. but when i run `cabal build` i get the same error `fatal: Could not parse object 'c30d0de6875d75edd64d1aac2272886528bc492d'`.

```
Cloning into '/home/cardano/projects/github/atlas-examples/dist-newstyle/src/servant-o_-d7933ffd24e60785'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1757, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (357/357), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (47/47), done.
remote: Total 1757 (delta 320), reused 321 (delta 299), pack-reused 1400
Receiving objects: 100% (1757/1757), 385.48 KiB | 1.68 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (818/818), done.
HEAD is now at 4165b83 Allow lens-aeson 1.2 (#27)
Cloning into '/home/cardano/projects/github/atlas-examples/dist-newstyle/src/blockfros_-88bd16c71266eeaf'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1524, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (70/70), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (44/44), done.
remote: Total 1524 (delta 35), reused 28 (delta 23), pack-reused 1454
Receiving objects: 100% (1524/1524), 264.98 KiB | 1.11 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1025/1025), done.
HEAD is now at 206e1a0 Merge pull request #39 from blockfrost/release/api-0.8.1
Cloning into '/home/cardano/projects/github/atlas-examples/dist-newstyle/src/atlas-bc9347bbf4453d47'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3615, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1258/1258), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (458/458), done.
remote: Total 3615 (delta 802), reused 1048 (delta 689), pack-reused 2357
Receiving objects: 100% (3615/3615), 986.51 KiB | 3.29 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2122/2122), done.
HEAD is now at e98e072 Merge pull request #235 from geniusyield/196-no-separate-change-output-for-fee-over-approximation
Cloning into '/home/cardano/projects/github/atlas-examples/dist-newstyle/src/plutus-si_-405d5a8470902f38'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3780, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (455/455), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (189/189), done.
remote: Total 3780 (delta 213), reused 419 (delta 193), pack-reused 3325
Receiving objects: 100% (3780/3780), 776.16 KiB | 2.10 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1895/1895), done.
HEAD is now at 0cb63af Added function to know output references at a payment credential
Cloning into '/home/cardano/projects/github/atlas-examples/dist-newstyle/src/bech32-b0701c420aaaffda'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3973, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (232/232), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (88/88), done.
remote: Total 3973 (delta 146), reused 188 (delta 124), pack-reused 3741
Receiving objects: 100% (3973/3973), 12.37 MiB | 13.76 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2808/2808), done.
HEAD is now at e341e7f Bump copyright years. (#57)
Cloning into '/home/cardano/projects/github/atlas-examples/dist-newstyle/src/cardano-a_-69e96f3eceed3ed5'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 21355, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3108/3108), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (776/776), done.
remote: Total 21355 (delta 2386), reused 2988 (delta 2286), pack-reused 18247
Receiving objects: 100% (21355/21355), 76.06 MiB | 20.55 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (16643/16643), done.
HEAD is now at 6b55f96d Merge pull request #223 from input-output-hk/paweljakubas/mbo-preparation
Cloning into '/home/cardano/projects/github/atlas-examples/dist-newstyle/src/cardano-s_-dd52ae23692dff9'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 313, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (167/167), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (78/78), done.
remote: Total 313 (delta 64), reused 162 (delta 64), pack-reused 146
Receiving objects: 100% (313/313), 1.00 MiB | 3.09 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (114/114), done.
HEAD is now at a91add1 update aeson v2
Cloning into '/home/cardano/projects/github/atlas-examples/dist-newstyle/src/cardano-w_-c9e033b0ec7ad11b'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 295476, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (13988/13988), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5178/5178), done.
remote: Total 295476 (delta 7416), reused 12780 (delta 6485), pack-reused 281488
Receiving objects: 100% (295476/295476), 243.78 MiB | 27.35 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (198692/198692), done.
HEAD is now at 3f0d2f3abe Release v2023-07-18 (#4046)
Cloning into '/home/cardano/projects/github/atlas-examples/dist-newstyle/src/haskell-s_-e5692cba7ac918b3'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1798, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (412/412), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (198/198), done.
remote: Total 1798 (delta 179), reused 371 (delta 174), pack-reused 1386
Receiving objects: 100% (1798/1798), 279.41 KiB | 1.31 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (994/994), done.
HEAD is now at 3c4efcc Merge branch 'main' into drop-v0
Cloning into '/home/cardano/projects/github/atlas-examples/dist-newstyle/src/openapi3-8b632f0d82841c8c'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4264, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (318/318), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (120/120), done.
remote: Total 4264 (delta 209), reused 256 (delta 164), pack-reused 3946
Receiving objects: 100% (4264/4264), 953.71 KiB | 3.08 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2080/2080), done.
fatal: Could not parse object 'c30d0de6875d75edd64d1aac2272886528bc492d'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This commit was used due to dependency upon [`cardano-wallet`](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-wallet) library. [Recently](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-wallet/pull/4225), it was updated on their end, consequently we had to update it as well, as in [this](https://github.com/geniusyield/atlas/pull/251) PR.

Atlas should build well with latest commit of `main`. If you have trouble building it, then [our CI file](https://github.com/geniusyield/atlas/blob/main/.github/workflows/haskell.yml) should help.

Unfortunately, `atlas-examples` repository isn't updated in sync with latest Atlas changes. Maybe you can help with it :)

Comment: I changed the tag and the sha of the opanapi3 repo as shown in the file changes of the PR you linked. however now i get a different set of errors. something `Error: cabal: Could not resolve dependencies` something about a version constraint `caused the previous version to fail: excluded by constraint '^>=4.14.1.0' from
'atlas')`. i would share with you the whole error but comments in stack exchange don't allow me to post the entire error.